# Why tomcat can reload my modified class if I started tomcat in debug mode?

Tags: java, tomcat, jvm

The similar question is 
[Dynamic class reloading works only in debug mode, why/ how it really works?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10581127/dynamic-class-reloading-works-only-in-debug-mode-why-how-it-really-works)
, but I was still confused and I have other questions.

When I was developing web application and using tomcat, If I start it using debug mode. The changed code can be put into effective immediately without restarting.

How can it be implemented?

Why the effect of changed code was determined by the tomcat start mode?

Why the changed code cannot take effect if I change the method name?(I know If I change the code of method body, it works)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Q> Why the effect of changed code was determined by the tomcat start mode?
A> [Hotswap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/jpda/enhancements.html#hotswap) functionality is a feature of JPDA, Java<sup>TM</sup> Platform Debugger Architecture. It was added in Java v1.4.2. Read the link for more information.

Q> How can it be implemented?
A> It's a feature of HotSpot JVM

Q> Why the changed code cannot take effect if I change the method name?
A> I'm guessing - because supporting changed method signatures would require much more work to implement. It's like re-linking every single class/method in the runtime. Car analogy: it's like changing all of your four tires while driving ;-). If you need this feature, consider other 3rd party tools, such as JRebel.